# 404 error on including extra url patterns with Django

Tags: html, django, http-status-code-404

I got a basic 404 error trouble with my django app which I am not able to solve... Maybe one could give me a hint ?

So my problem is the following : I am currently developing a website with analysis tools for several phone services. Each service has its own serviceid number in the database to be able to analyse it alone. Therefore, I am using relative url instead of hardcoding everything as it is the smartest solution, providing the serviceid to my views.py.

I thought that using relative url would be the best solution as each service is analyzed exactly in the same way. I managed to do it in html for the template pages but when I call one of these webpage, I found a 404 error. For example, when I call portal/desiractif/duree, it is a 404 error but when I call portal/desiractif on its own, it is working...

I used https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs as an example.

So here is my urls.py :

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

extra_patterns = [
    url(r'^$', "analytics.views.service_views.service_index"),
    url(r'^duree/$', "analytics.views.service_views.service_duree"),
    url(r'^fixevsmobile/$', "analytics.views.service_views.service_fixvsmobile"),
]

urlpatterns = [
    ....
    url(r'^portal/desiractif/$', include(extra_patterns), {'serviceid' : serviceid}),
    ....
]
```

And here part of my html code with the relative links between pages :

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
   <li role="presentation"><a href="">Index</a></li>
   <li role="presentation"><a href="fixevsmobile">Fixe vs mobile</a></li>
   <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Behaviour</a></li>
   <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Rappels</a></li>
   <li role="presentation"><a href="duree">Time</a></li>
</ul>
```

In other words, relative html links are working but Django returns 404 error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be :

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

extra_patterns = [
    url(r'^$', "analytics.views.service_views.service_index"),
    url(r'^duree/$', "analytics.views.service_views.service_duree"),
    url(r'^fixevsmobile/$', "analytics.views.service_views.service_fixvsmobile"),
]

urlpatterns = [
    ....
    # Remove the '$' at the end of regex expression
    url(r'^portal/desiractif/', include(extra_patterns), {'serviceid' : serviceid}),
    ....
]
```

**There should not be `$` at the end of `r'^portal/desiractif/$'`.** This causes regex to match only patterns `portal/desiractif/` and not anything after `portal/desiractif/....`. Since the regex could not match requested url with any of the url patterns, it returns `404 error`.

**`$` (Dollar sign):**

`$` matches the end of the string. It represents the end of the current line in multi-line mode, otherwise the end of the string.

If my regex was `b$`, then it will match `b` at the end of the string:

```
'b'     # Matches 'b' in 'b'
'ab'    # Matches 'b' in 'ab'
'abc'   # Does not match
```

Answer (score 2):

```
url(r'^portal/desiractif/'...
```

Remove `$` in the end.